# How can you check Search API Quota usage in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

For a few days in a row I have a Search API error:

```
OverQuotaError: The API call search.IndexDocument() 
required more quota than is available.
```

I almost sure that I have not reached [quota limits] but I cannot find a way to make sure.

How can I check current quota usage, if not in admin them maybe by code.

Comment: Have you checked it again? I'm observing the same problem, though the quota details look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now check your Search API Quota from within the Quota Admin Console.  It is located below the **Storage** section, of the **Quote Details** page.  This feature was added yesterday (5-23-2012) and was blogged about on [the official Google App Engine Blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/05/166-sdk-released.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20GoogleAppEngineBlog%20%28Google%20App%20Engine%20Blog%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader).

Answer (score 2):

You can't check Search quota usage right now.  It'll be viewable in admin console soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can check quotas for all Google services which provides API [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console). I don't find Custom Search API there although.

Comment: This is not for Google App Engine

Answer (score 0):

I found [quotas on appengine search api for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567267/quotas-on-appengine-search-api-for-java)
which says that there is a rate limiting at about 100 to 120 API calls per minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you need additional quota for the App Engine search API, you can request it [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dFFJUi1GUW1mVGpOQllJUjBUOUVJUUE6MQ#gid=0).