# Need Clarification of App Engine SearchAPI Quota

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm experimenting with the Search API with appengine, and am consistently running into the "short term burst quota" described in this SO post: [quotas on appengine search api for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567267/quotas-on-appengine-search-api-for-java).

In our use case, we need to delete all documents from an Index, and re-populate the index. We've attacked this by:

1. Looping through the list and deleting documents
2. Adding documents through a task queue (1/s) throughput rate

I'm *still* bumping against this burst limit and I'm wondering if I might have to put a sleep when I delete the documents?

This burst rate is severely limiting us (since we are building these indexes on the fly based on other criteria) and am curious if anyone has any more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should limit the usage using a queue and not sleep (never ever use sleep in AppEngine).
2. You can request an [increase on your quota](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dFFJUi1GUW1mVGpOQllJUjBUOUVJUUE6MQ).

Comment: Thanks Shay for the quick response. I requested more.

Comment: Shay-- Quick follow-up. I'm assuming that removing documents from an index is also included in the quota count. Do you know if this is correct?

Comment: @user1453956 remove also has quota, but I don't know if its shared with the indexing quot.a

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a 100 calls per minute quota as well as 20k per day (although the per minute quota may now have been removed).

The best way around this that I have found is with cursors and taskqueues to spread the load.